# Case statement logic and substring

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have the following data:

```
Passes
ID   |  Pass_code
-----------------
100  |  2xBronze 
101  |  1xGold
102  |  1xSilver
103  |  2xSteel

Passengers
ID   |  Passengers
-----------------
100  |  2
101  |  5
102  |  1
103  |  3
```

I want to count then create a ticket in the output of:

```
ID 100 | 2 pass (bronze)
ID 101 | 5 pass (because it is gold, we count all passengers)
ID 102 | 1 pass (silver)
ID 103 | 2 pass (steel)
```

I was thinking something like the code below however, I am unsure how to finish my case statement. I want to substring pass_code so that we get show pass numbers e.g '2xBronze' should give me 2. Then for ID 103, we have 2 passes and 3 customers so we should output 2.

Also, is there a way to firstly find '2xbronze' if the pass_code contained lots of other things such as '101001, 1xbronze, FirstClass' - this may change so i don't want to substring, could we search for '2xbronze' and then pull out the 2??

```
 SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN Passes.pass_code like '%gold%' THEN Passengers.passengers
      WHEN Passes.pass_code like '%steel%' THEN SUBSTRING(passes.pass_code, 1,1)
      WHEN Passes.pass_code like '%bronze%' THEN SUBSTRING(passes.pass_code, 1,1)
      WHEN Passes.pass_code like '%silver%' THEN SUBSTRING(passes.pass_code, 1,1)
      else  0 end as no,
   Passes.ID, 
   Passes.Pass_code, 
   Passengers.Passengers

FROM Passes
JOIN Passengers ON Passes.ID = Passengers.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db698e8562546ae7658270e0ec26ca54

Comment: A `case` _expression_´s different return values must have compatible data types. strings and integers aren't.

Comment: What if there's `10xSomething` ? You really should fix your DB design

Comment: Add tag for database used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you are indeed using Oracle (as your DB fiddle implies).

You can do some string magic with finding position of a splitter character (in your case the x), then substringing based on that. Obviously this has it's problems, and x is a bad character seperator as well.. but based on your current set.

```
 WITH PASSCODESPLIT AS
 (
  SELECT PASSES.ID, 
  TO_Number(SUBSTR(PASSES.PASS_CODE, 0, (INSTR(PASSES.PASS_CODE, 'x')) - 1)) AS NrOfPasses,
  SUBSTR(PASSES.PASS_CODE, (INSTR(PASSES.PASS_CODE, 'x')) + 1) AS PassType
  FROM Passes
 )
 SELECT 
   PASSCODESPLIT.ID,
   CASE 
   WHEN PASSCODESPLIT.PassType = 'gold' THEN Passengers.Passengers
   ELSE PASSCODESPLIT.NrOfPasses
   END AS NrOfPasses,
   PASSCODESPLIT.PassType,
   Passengers.Passengers
FROM PASSCODESPLIT
INNER JOIN Passengers ON PASSCODESPLIT.ID = Passengers.ID
ORDER BY PASSCODESPLIT.ID ASC
```

Gives the result of:

```
ID    NROFPASSES    PASSTYPE    PASSENGERS
100   2             bronze      2
101   5             gold        5
102   1             silver      1
103   2             steel       3
```

As can also be seen in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99d29aafcb2cb74ecc1f7ff091a0bd5a)

But I would strongly advise you to **fix your table design**. Having multiple attributes in the same column leads to troubles like these. And the more variables/variations you start storing, the more 'magic' you need to keep doing.

In this particular example i see no reason why you don't simply have the 3 columns in Passes, also giving you the opportunity to add new columns going forward. I.e. to keep track of First class.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the numbers using `regexp_substr()`.  So I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.pass_code LIKE '%gold%'
             THEN TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p.pass_code, '^[0-9]+'))
             ELSE pp.passengers
         END) as num,
      p.ID, p.Pass_code, pp.Passengers
FROM Passes p JOIN
     Passengers pp
     ON p.ID = pp.ID;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80d264c37b4f82042523636a0f0adcc4) is a db<>fiddle.

This converts the leading digits in the code to a number.  Also note the use of table aliases to simplify the query.